# New instance of a class with next.js not working

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to use a js carousel (siema) in a next.js app, but can't get it to work. I get errors no matter what I try.

I have a slideshow component called HomeSlideShow.js:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Siema from "../.next/static/js/siema";

const HomeSlideShow = props => (
 <div>
   <Head>
    <script type="module" src="_next/static/js/siema.js" />
  </Head>
  <div className="siema">
    <div>Hi, I'm slide 1</div>
    <div>Hi, I'm slide 2</div>
    <div>Hi, I'm slide 3</div>
    <div>Hi, I'm slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
);

export default HomeSlideShow;
```

I'm importing the component in the index.js file:

```
import HomeSlideShow from "../components/HomeSlideShow";

const Index = props => (
  <Layout>
   <HomeSlideShow />
  </Layout>
);
```

I just don't know how to initialise the slider using:

```
new Siema();
```

Or:

```
<script>
 new Siema();
</script>
```

as per the docs. Wherever I try it, it errors. Any pointers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert function component into class component and try to initialize siema plugin inside [`componentDidMount` lifycycle method as it is executed after initial `render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting)

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Siema from '../.next/static/js/siema';

class HomeSlideShow extends React.component {
  componentDidMount() {
    new Siema();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <script type="module" src="_next/static/js/siema.js" />
        </Head>
        <div className="siema">
          <div>Hi, I'm slide 1</div>
          <div>Hi, I'm slide 2</div>
          <div>Hi, I'm slide 3</div>
          <div>Hi, I'm slide 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeSlideShow;
```

Hope this helps!